# How to run a web service from eclipse on another machine/real server

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I'm new to the Java world and I managed to create a web service, run it on Tomcat server and use it in my Silverlight project.

The problem is I don't know how to start this service on a Windows machine that doesn't have Eclipse.

More importantly, how can I start it on a real server? A tutorial or step-by-step guide would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read the FAQ for the relevant version of Tomcat? For example, for version 7.0, the [Setup](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html) page of the docs gives some information, as well as linking to the docs for [running Tomcat as a Windows service](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html).

Of course, configuring Tomcat to run your servlet is a separate task, but the Tomcat docs are pretty comprehensive.

If you're still running into problems after reading those docs very carefully, please edit your question to tell us exactly which bits you're having problems with.

Comment: +1 for reading the docs.  I've found the tomcat docs to normally be quite complete.  If I remember correctly when using the windows installer for tomcat there is an option for adding the tomcat service.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from an Eclipse web services project, you can right click on it > Export > WAR file, selecting Tomcat webapps folder as destination. Like any other webapp project.

Tell me if I missed the point.